# "Sticky" paramter doesnt change the window at all

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am just building my first tkinter window and I am a little puzzled. I created a label and a Button and set them in them same row but different columns.

Now the placement of the button changes depending on the length of the text in the label. To fix this I wanted to "stick" the label and the button to east/west respectively and add a small amount of padding.

Now the issue, no matter what variant of "sticky" I add it doesn't affect the placement of anything at all.

Below are the two code variants that all lead to the same output window:

```
from tkinter import * 

def Btt_ShowAll_clicked():
    print("klicked")  

#create the window
Main_Window = Tk()

#Modify the Window
Main_Window.title("Ressourcen Verwaltung")

Lbl_Descr_a = Label(Main_Window, text = "Einträge einsehen")#Create Label
Lbl_Descr_a.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10) #Show Label


Btt_ShowAll_a = Button(Main_Window, text="Einträge anzeigen")
Btt_ShowAll_a.bind("<Button-1>",Btt_ShowAll_clicked)#Button click starts function
Btt_ShowAll_a.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
#In the line above Change "W" to "E" ord delet the "sticky = W" alltogether and nothing changes in the window

Main_Window.geometry('350x200') #Window size


#Make the windows stay (loop)      
Main_Window.mainloop()
```

What can I do to get the desired output?

Shouldn't "sticky" stick it to the given side and then with padx I should be able to choose how close it is said side?

Comment: For your case, use `sticky=E` for the button and add `Main_Window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As far as I know, you have to type sticky='w' instead of sticky=W, should work then.

Comment: `W` is a constant in `tkinter` which equals `'w'` and it is imported by the import statement at the beginning of the code: `from tkinter import *`.